# HTTP Call type cast error in flutter issue

Tags: flutter, dart

### EDIT

I tried this

```
@override
void initState () {
  super.initState();

  features = getFeatureStatus(user.userId).then((f) {
   setState((){features = f;});
  });
}
```

But I get this analyzer error.

> A value of type 'Future' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Features'.
>   Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Features'.dart(invalid_assignment)

---

EDIT END

I have this http call, Features is just an object with 8 values.

### HTTP CALL

```
Future<Features> getFeatureStatus(String userID) async {
  final response = await http.post(
    'http://url/api/FeaturesGet',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    },
    body: json.encode({'userID' : userID }),
  );

  // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON 

  return Features.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
}
```

### Implementation

```
 @override
 void initState () {
   super.initState();
   features = getFeatureStatus(user.userId) as Features;
 }
```

Im getting this error and Im not sure how to fix it. It looks correct code wise. We normally do these on button clicks and pass the object around the application but we need this to work on init.

> type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Features' in type cast

Comment: You cannot do this: `features = getFeatureStatus( ... etc...` - see the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign a `Future<T>` to a `T`. Normally you'd `await` the future, or you can use `.then`.

```
  getFeatureStatus(widget.user.userId).then((f){
    setState((){features = f;});
  });
```

Comment: Reproduce the code above exactly. Do not add the extraneous `features=` at the start.

Comment: Note that features will be null until the http response is received, so allow for that in your build - for example, render a progress indicator while it is null.

Comment: That worked, its throwing a quick error that goes away almost right away where I check one of the values and its null then it works as it should. Is there a way for me to prevent that?

Comment: See the comment on the line above.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // this is randomly declared
  Features features;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getFeatureStatus();
    // Or you can use the second method
    getFeatureStatus(user.userId).then((f) {
      // here you will get the features object where you can later play with it
    });
  }

  getFeatureStatus() async {
    features = await getFeatureStatus(user.userId);
    // in this you can later us the objct in the way you want
  }

  Future<Features> getFeatureStatus(String userID) async {
    Features _features;

    final response = await http.post('http://35.226.136.162/api/FeaturesGet',
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
        body: json.encode({'userID': userID}));
    _features = Features.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));

    return _features;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(child: Center(child: Text('Loading Data'))),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Features {
  // your defination defined 
}
```